# Asymptotic returns expression unchanged instead of first-order approximation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm using `Asymptotic` to get first-order expansion of `expr=Gamma[0, s/10] - Gamma[0, s]`, and it returns `expr` unchanged.

Any idea why?

```
expr = Gamma[0, s/10] - Gamma[0, s];
expr = Gamma[0, s/10] - Gamma[0, s];
asymptotic1 = Asymptotic[expr, {s, 0, 1}] (*returns Log[10] *)
asymptotic2 = 
 Asymptotic[
  expr, {s, 0, 2}] (*returns -(9 s)/10+(99 s^2)/400+Log[10] *)
approx = -0.9 s + 2.3025;
Plot[{expr, approx}, {s, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> {"original", approx}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"s"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The `Asymptotic` is being done with the wrong variable. Use `s` rather than `x`

Comment: Ooops fixed. So the curious thing is that `Asymptotic[expr, {s, 0, 1}]` gives 0th order approximation, while `Asymptotic[expr, {s, 0, 2}]` gives 2nd order, it doesn't give 1st order for some reason, but it seems it should exist

Comment: Use `Series[expr, {s, 0, 1}] // Normal` to get `-((9 s)/10) + Log[10]`